# Set property `OnClick` on Hyperlink tag in markup aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, popupwindow

In markup of my aspx page I have set this `Hyperlink` tag :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="myField">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="myField" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("myField").ToString()) ? String.Format("Validate.aspx?sId={0}", Eval("id").ToString()) : "") %>'
            ImageUrl='<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("myField").ToString()) ? "/img/redbul.gif" : "/img/forestbul.gif")%>'
            ToolTip='<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("myField").ToString()) ? "empty" : "full")%>'
            Target="_blank" BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="Transparent" OnClick="window.open(this.href,'playsample','width=500,height=500,left=100,top=100,scrollbars=yes,dependent=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,directories=no,menubar=no,status=no,resizable=yes');return false;">
        </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And set on the property `OnClick` for opening of a new web page in a popup window :

```
    OnClick="window.open(this.href,'playsample','width=500,height=500,left=100,top=100,  
  scrollbars=yes,dependent=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,directories=no,menubar=no,
    status=no,resizable=yes');return false;">
```

But I can't to :

1. Set on the property `OnClick` the confirm popup before opening of a new web page in a popup window;
2. Prevent the opening of pop-up window when the value of the `myfield` is full; in this case the property `OnClick` open an empty web window.

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance.

**Edit #1**

```
<td class="ddl_Class_new" align="center">
<a id="gvProducts_ctl03_myField" title="Full" OnClick="if(!confirm(&#39;Continue ?&#39;))return false;
window.open(this.href,&#39;playsample&#39;,&#39;width=500,height=500,left=100,top=100,scrollbars=yes,dependent=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,
directories=no,menubar=no,status=no,resizable=yes&#39;);return false;" target="_blank" style="display:inline-block;color:Transparent;border-style:None;">
<img title="Full" src="/Img/forestbul.gif" alt="" style="border-width:0px;" /></a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. javascript, if confirm(....) window.open
2. "when the value of the myfield is full" - check with jquery

Edit 1:

jquery for question 2:

if ( $("#<%# myField.ClientID %>").attr('value') == "Full" ) ) ...

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, I have solved my first problem with your suggestion, I don' t find anything for second problem....

Comment: pls add the generated html code to your question and be a little bit more specific on this and i will try to help more

Comment: Ok thank you, I have voted for your answer and in **Edit #1** in my first question you find the generated html code when the value of the myfield is full. Hope in your help.